# Programming differences with LINQ and EF if you use Oracle instead of SQL Server as a DB?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio

Will changing to `Oracle` from `SQL Server` require changing any of the existing `LINQ` or `Entity Framework` development of a .NET application?  The project is currently using `SQL Server` but there is a recommendation (not a requirement) to use `Oracle`.

Comment: Is there a programming question somewhere in there?  Besides, it's off-topic.

Comment: This type of question is a poor fit for StackOverflow, as any answer you get will be a matter of opinion.  All database systems have pluses and negatives.

Comment: Not directly but I mention using `LINQ` and `Entity Framework` with `Oracle` vs `SQL Server`.

Comment: if they insist on Oracle, double the price since you have to re-engineer the solution to fit a different RDBMS, and see if their convictions stick. :)

Comment: If you have good separation of layers it shouldn't be a big deal to swap out the DBMS. Just change the data access layer and everything else should still work.

Comment: @iamkrillin I added a line at the bottom of the question to clarify.  I'm not asking which is a better database.  I'm asking if there are clear reasons for using SQL Server over Oracle if the development is in Visual Studio, NET, LINQ, EF.

Comment: @Jeremy Since it sounds like a new project, your point is moot IMO

Comment: @Heinrich To the best of my knowledge, Oracle is well supported in the .net space (including linq) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: @Heinrich: from a code-perspective, there should be functionally no difference between Oracle and SQL Server, if you're using an ORM like Entity Framework. As long as the ORM supports the database, you're good.

Comment: If your Oracle is below 12c you will need to review all of your Linq-Statements, since in nested EXISTS (nested Any() in Linq) Oracle will lose values from from scope starting from the third nested level. It is quite possible, that EF will produce such queries. Also Lazy-Loading of Childs morre than a dot away (x.y.z) may not work. If you use Code First you will need to seperate your Oracle- from your MSSQL-Migrations and review them possibly, as Oracle has some strange restrictions regarding the length of names. And yes: Double your price.

Comment: @user3411327 Thank you, this is exactly the type of information I was looking for regarding the impact on Linq and EF by using Oracle instead of SQL Server.  You clearly point out some differences between Linq/EF compatibility with Oracle vs Sql Server that a developer needs to be aware of.  Here you point out that yes the ORM (EF) supports Oracle but there are programming differences to be aware of.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

An ORM is a layer to abstract you away from the database. Ideally you won't know what the underlying DB is.

I would get an evaluation copy of Oracle and point your EF at it. The EF is very good at communicating with DBs and I doubt you will have any problem.

Practically you may run into different issues; but until you do some research and ask specific questions about issues this community will be of no help. If you have a data engineer leave it to them to decide on the DBMS and you choose a robust ORM (EF) to abstract you.